# Download virtual box and run windows in it

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, 22.04, virtualbox

I want to download VirtualBox on Ubuntu 22.04 and run Windows on it. I just installed Ubuntu and I'm new to it so I don't know much about it. While installing VirtualBox via `apt get install virtual...` it shows this error:

```
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'virtualbox-7.0_7.0.12-159484~Ubuntu~jammy_amd64.deb'
```

Can anyone please guide me through it?